# How to create multiple typedefs of similar format?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, typedef

I'm dynamically loading a DLL that has quite a few methods and I have a typedef that handles several of the DLL methods:

```
typedef int32_t (__cdecl *MYPROC)(const char *url, const char *options, const char *body, int32_t length); // GET, POST, HTTP test
```

Whenever I create another typedef to handle a separate function:

```
typedef int32_t (__cdecl *MYPROC)(const char *json_blob, const char *response, int32_t length); // ParseVal
```

I am met with errors about conflicting declarations:

```
conflicting declaration 'typedef int32_t (__attribute__((cdecl)) * MYPROC)(const char*, const char*, int32_t)'
 typedef int32_t (__cdecl *MYPROC)(const char *json_blob, const char *response, int32_t length); // ParseVal
                                                                                              ^
note: previous declaration as 'typedef int32_t (__attribute__((cdecl)) * MYPROC)(const char*, const char*, const char*, int32_t)'
 typedef int32_t (__cdecl *MYPROC)(const char *url, const char *options, const char *body, int32_t length); // GET, POST, HTTP test
```

I'm unsure if this is the correct approach to handle the DLL methods so I am open to suggestions. I am new to this feature of C++ and haven't used the language in quite some time so apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: Why are you naming both type aliases `MYPROC`? It's the same as trying `typedef int T; typedef float T;` - obviously the **type** `T` can't be declared to refer to two different types.

Comment: Ah. I see now. I was looking it as MYPROC being a system defined type instead of a name.. which would defeat the whole purpose of using a typedef. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica). I was thinking MYPROC was WinAPI defined and not a name for some reason.